# Can't get app to publish collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

New to imports and exports. I'm struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I want to publish my Profile.js collection while using the recommended file structure in Meteor.

Path: `imports/api/profile/server/publications.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Profile } from '../../profile/Profile.js';

Meteor.publish('profile.private', function() {
  if (!this.userId) {
    return this.ready();
  }
  return Profile.find({
    userId: this.userId
  });
});
```

Path: `imports/api/profile/Profile.js`

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { AddressSchema } from '../../api/profile/AddressSchema.js';
import { ContactNumberSchema } from '../../api/profile/ContactNumberSchema.js';

SimpleSchema.debug = true;

export const Profile = new Mongo.Collection("profile");

Profile.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;
    }
});


var Schemas = {};

Schemas.Profile = new SimpleSchema({
    userId: {
      type: String,
      // regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
      optional: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    familyName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    mobileNumber: {
      type: ContactNumberSchema,
      optional: false
    },
});

Profile.attachSchema(Schemas.Profile);
```

Path: `client/pages/newSite/users-all/main.js`

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import { Profile } from '../../../../imports/api/profile/Profile.js';
import './main.html';

Template.main.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('profile.private');
    });
});
```

Comment: assuming client is a top level directory, the import you're doing in main.js looks like it's going too far out of the app. If client and import folders are at the same level, it should just be '../imports/the rest of the path'

Comment: Ok, I've changed that and now in the browser console I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../imports/api/profile/Profile.js'`

Comment: with /imports at the top, i don't use a relative path. instead, "/imports/api/profile/Profile". Also, note i don't have the ".js" at the end. unsure if that's your issue, hence a comment instead of an answer, but that's what i would try first.

Comment: Sorry, I've made an edit for the main.js path. I'm trying to make some major changes to make the app to give it proper structure and compatible for meteor 1.4. As a result, I have files everywhere. The main.js file is currently buried a little deeper in the file tree.

Comment: @bp123, that's an even better reason to use an absolute path to get things inside of /imports, rather than a relative one: when you move around files referencing items in /imports, you don't have to worry about fixing up the relative pathing.

Comment: @bp123 I'd try what @zim said and see if absolute path gets you anywhere. I import with the `.js` extension so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: None of the suggestions appear to work. Am I suppose to import the publications.js file into the main.js file. I've tried however whenever I do this I get `Cannot find module`

Comment: @bp123, all your pathing looks okay (though i still prefer absolute paths). i think your Profile export should work as is, but just for fun, in your Profile.js, change "export const" to just "const" and, at the bottom, export it there: "export {Profile};"

Comment: @zim It looks like the Profile collection is now visible (I can see it using meteortoys:allthings). The problem is no data is flowing back up. I've removed all conditions to try and return everything however it's still not coming through.

Comment: I reposted this question in a different way. It turns out it's to do with additional setup that I wasn't aware I needed. Thanks for all the suggestions! See answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245291/seperate-publish-function-our-of-schema-and-into-server-publications-js/42246900#42246900